# Why are we not allowed to specify a constructor in an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface defining a constructor signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619856/interface-defining-a-constructor-signature)

I know that you cannot specify a constructor in an interface in .Net, but why can we not?

It would be really useful for my current project to be able to specify that an 'engine' must be passed in with the constructor, but as I cant, I have to suffice with an XML comment on the class.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Because an interface describes behaviour. Constructors aren't behaviour. How an object is built is an implementation detail.

Comment: I think that's putting attaching too much meaning to an implementation detail: a constructor in .NET is really just a method that gets called immediately after the object is created (allocated in memory). There is no reason it can't be defined as behaviour as well. Of course, implementations are free to declare other constructors as well, just as they can overload a method that implements an interface.

Constructors in interfaces would be a rarely-used feature, but not a useless one.

Comment: I think the point of the question is: since it is built this way, what is the best practice? So I suppose the answer is: by using abstract classes, as this answer states: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2804067/1181162

Comment: A public constructor is obviously part of the API. What else could that be if not behaviour?

Answer (score 28):

How would you call the constructor? When you use interfaces, you normally pass an instance of the interface around (or rather, a reference). Also bear in mind that if one class implements an interface, a derived class inherits that interface, but may not have the same set of constructors.

Now, I can see the use of what I call *static interfaces* for specifying constructors and other essentially static members for use in generic methods. See [my blog post on the idea](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces/) for more information.

Comment: +1 I think this would be a great addition to .NET and I've upvoted the associated Connect feedback item: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/412848/allow-structural-type-constraints-for-generic-type-parameters

Comment: I can think of three class-ish features of interfaces: (1) default implementations for methods or properties (note that inherited interfaces would not be able to override those of the base); (2) allowing the same identifier to effectively double as an interface and a static class; (3) defining a static method to be used when "new" is called on the interface.  Note that #2 and #3 would be syntactic sugar, but I think they'd make some things cleaner.  If .net supported #1, interfaces could have new methods or properties added without breaking existing implementations.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, I've been thinking about 1 for a while too - and so has MS, I believe. There's an interview with Vance Morrison where he talks about this.

Comment: I'm curious to know what's being done re #1; I'd also like to know if Microsoft is adding any nice means of cleaning up IDisposables when constructors throw exceptions, or (for vb) if there's going to be a way to automatically kill all WithEvents subscriptions.  I've seen some links for old discussions of new features; do you have anything up-to-date?

Comment: @supercat: No idea, I'm afraid. I haven't heard about anything around that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Could you explain what you mean by static interfaces? It sounds like you mean an interface that cant be instantiated, but interfaces cant be instantiated at all so that doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @kingfrito_5005: Did you read the blog post that I linked to?

Comment: @JonSkeet I did, but honestly I was more confused after reading it than I was going in.

Comment: @kingfrito_5005: In that case I suggest you ignore the whole second paragraph. I doubt that explaining it again (which would take more than a comment) will help.

Answer (score 9):

No you can not have constructors on interfaces for the reasons that have been posted. However you can on abstract classes. Lets say for example you have this base class.

```
public abstract class ClassOne
{
    protected int _x;
    protected string _s;

    public ClassOne(int x, string s)
    {
        _x = x;
        _s = s;
    }        
}
```

Notice there is no constructors that takes no argument (default constructor) which means any class that inherits from ClassOne must call the constructor that has 2 arguments.

So this is not valid and will not compile.

```
public class ClassTwo : ClassOne
{
    public ClassTwo() 
    { }
}
```

However this is valid and will compile.

```
public class ClassTwo : ClassOne
{
    public ClassTwo(int x, string s) : base(x, s)
    {  }
}
```

I would like to point out here that in C# you can only inherit from one base class. Meaning that this may not be the correct solution for particular situation but is something to think about.

Tony.

Comment: Since classes cant inherit constructors, I think this is only a partial solution because it requires the subclass to implement its constructor call in a special way, but doesnt guarantee that the subclass has a constructor with the same signature.

Answer (score 8):

Among all the other reasons already posted, keep also in mind the a class can easily implement several interfaces; which constructor should be used then?

Comment: There's a perfectly good syntax for implementing interface methods with the same signature that could be used for the constructors.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point (maybe I didn't): I meant that class A can implement interfaces IAlpha with a constructor with no arguments, IBeta with a constructor with one arguments and IGamma with a constructor with two arguments: which constructor should class A implement?

Comment: Ah, this is the only answer that really makes sense to me. All the arguments that you can't instantiate an interface leave me asking "So what?" The point of an interface is to declare that such-and-such a set of functions must be implemented in any class that presumes to implement the interface. It sounds reasonable to say that such a class should also have to implement a constructor taking this particular set of arguments. But the clashing constructors argument, now that presents a problem.

Comment: Totally agree with Jay. Although I believe its not an absurd idea to enforce constructor signature through interface, a lot more thought needs to be put in.

Comment: It wouldnt be hard for .net to simply disallow the implementation of interfaces with identical method signatures. In fact, doesnt it do that? If not I think it should regardless of the constructor question.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers have already pointed out why it doesn't make sense to have a constructor declaration on an interface. But from your question, I'm guessing that you are probably looking for the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory).

To give an example based on your question: you say that you would like to somehow declare that an 'engine' must be passed to the constructor. You can do this by declaring a separate interface for a construction service like this:

```
public interface IGadgetFactory
{
   IGadget CreateGadget(Engine engine);
}
```

Any code which must create `IGadget` instances can then use an `IGadgetFactory` instance instead of calling any constructors directly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cant instantiate an interface, so a constructur doenst make sense.

Comment: How do abstract classes make sense then?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other explanations given here, you'd have to invent a new syntax for calling them anyway, since if you have two or more implementations in scope at the line:

```
Dim x as new IDoStuff()
```

Whice implementation gets called?

Comment: Were I designing a language, I would allow an interface to name a static method to be used, so the above statement would be equivalent to e.g. `Dim X As IDoStuff = IDoStuff_Creator.CreateNew();`