# Understanding this keyword in Java

Tags: java, applet, this

When events are registered in the `init()` method of the Applet, we add the method `addTypeListener(this)`.

But I know that the keyword `this` refers to the object that called the method. So, when we haven't created any object of the applet class what would the `this` refer to?
please clarify my doubts.

Comment: Just because *you* didn't create an instance of the class doesn't mean *nothing* did.

Comment: Once all constructors are finished, the object is created. `init()` is not a constructor and unless it is called from one, it will have the fully constructed object available.

Comment: +1, this is actually not the worst question in the world.

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the object that called the method, but the object the method was called **on**.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `this` works when you haven't *explicitly* created an instance of your Applet is because the JRE treats Applets a little differently.

Applets are a special class that **Java instantiates for you** upon loading. From there, the object is owned by the JRE and is interfaced with by such.

Once Java creates an instance of your applet, it then calls `init()` in lieu of a constructor (since [constructors cannot conform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804041/constructor-in-an-interface) to a prototypical [contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)).

Likewise, when your applet is done or the page is unloaded, Java worries about shutting down your applet.

Answer (score 1):

> But I know that the keyword this refers to the object that called the method.

That's not quite true. Actually in an instance method's code,
`this` refers to the object the method was called on.

> So, when we haven't created any object of the applet class what would the this refer to?

The JVM has created an object/instance of your Applet class (subclass that is),
so `this` refers to that instance of your Applet class.

Comment: Browsers don't have built-in JVMs.

Comment: At least, not any browsers currently :)

Answer (score -1):

'this' keyword refers to the object of the class on which you are working. 'This' keyword can be used to  call the default constructor of the class. Similarly while using inheritance concept, 'super' keyword is use to call the default constructor of the inherited class or can be referred as the inherited /parent class' object.

Comment: `super()` and `this` have nothing to do with default constructors in particular.

Comment: `'This' keyword can be used to call the default constructor of the class.` Wrong; `this` can be used in a constructor to call *any other* constructor. Likewise, `super` can be used to call any constructor of the direct parent class. Like `this`, `super` can be used in methods as well, to call parent versions of the method.