# Why don't Scala traits allow constructor parameters?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, coming from Java, and I was just reading about traits. One thing that gets mentioned often is that traits don't (can't?  won't?) have constructor parameters.  I was curious to know if there was a reason for this.

Coming from a long ago maths/computer-science background I was was wondering if this was an inevitable consequence because of some language design decision, or if it was a conscious decision to avoid some inheritance/mix-in problem or another?

Was hoping someone might know because it feels like there might be something interesting behind the fact.

Comment: Considering you can pretty much emulate constructor parameters by overriding vals and doing the rest of the constructor body lazily, I doubt that there's a deep reason behind it. Of course, maybe there is. Maybe something to do with Java/Scala interop?

Comment: Traits don't have constructors. That's pretty much the defining difference between classes and traits

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804041/constructor-in-an-interface

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answers describe the language; I suspect your question may really be "why is it designed in this way".

I believe it arises out of the awkwardnesses and verboseness that would arise when extending multiple traits, especially with overrides and with types, and various mix-in strategies.

The Cake Pattern often results in various traits providing missing bits to each other in a way that is totally invisible - by design - in the mixing class.  And mixing can be bi-directional, using [self-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses).  So the construction of a class from traits can be a very messy business for the compiler.  Scala often trades simplicity of compiler design and implementation for simplicity of language use and code reduction, and this is certainly a good example.

So while there may be simple, hierarchical cases where having a constructor might be useful and sufficient, it would almost certainly have to be redundant of other mechanisms for more difficult, non-hierarchical scenarios.

Comment: I don't agree with the conclusion, but gave +1 because you tried to answer the question as it was (probably?) intended.

Comment: @Madoc - It's a weak answer - I'm embarrassed by all the upvotes.  Hopefully, someone like Daniel will weigh in with specifics.

Comment: You are right about the intention behind my question though :) so thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Scala 3 will allow trait parameters. Here's a sample from the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/trait-parameters.html)

```scala
trait Greeting(val name: String) {
  def msg = s"How are you, $name"
}

class C extends Greeting("Bob") {
  println(msg)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: that's what Scala is right now.

But that might not be the case in the future: trait parameters can replace early initializers. (see Martin Odersky's recent [Scala Days](http://event.scaladays.org/scaladays-sanfran-2015) presentation page 34)
 [Scala: Where It Came From & Where It is Going](http://www.slideshare.net/Odersky/scala-days-san-francisco-45917092)

Answer (score 2):

Traits don't have constructor parameters because traits cannot be constructed. Given any trait `T` it's not possible to instantiate any object of type exactly `T`. You can override trait defs with vals though, so

```
trait Foo {
  def bar: String
}
class Baz(override val bar: String) extends Foo
```

You can't construct them directly because `new MyTrait {}` is actually sugar for an anonymous class of `new Object with MyTrait {}`

Comment: Hmm. The same logic would apply to abstract classes, wouldn't it? I would say that traits *should* be allowed to have constructors, and I also don't understand why they are not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Trait is analog for Java Interface. The main difference is that trait can have default implementation for their methods.

So Java interfaces can't have constructor so do Scala traits

Comment: This is not valid in Scala 3, in which traits can have parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Scala 3 allows [traits with parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/trait-parameters.html), just like classes have parameters.