# Passing constructor as a parameter to a method

Tags: java, constructor

I am new to java and started working on constructors. I am seeing few examples where constructor is passed as parameter to a Method. Please tell me what happens when a constructor is passed as a parameter to a method..or suggest me some links where can i get enough knowledge about using constructors

Comment: "*I am seeing few examples where constructor is passed as parameter to a Method.*" - While this is possible in Java, I have a feeling that you mean something else than you have written. Can you show us an example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"I am seeing few examples where constructor is passed as parameter to a Method."* That's unlikely. Post an example of what you're seeing that makes you think that.

Comment: @Turing85 `while this is possible in Java`  I am actually curious how you pass constructor as an argument. Do you have any links or sample codes on that?

Comment: @user3437460 [SpacePrez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027030/4216641) has a link to baeldung. There are some samples.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the purpose why do you need to pass the constructor you may consider passing the instance of Supplier instead (JavaDoc - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html). 
For example you have a method which suppose to create an account and fill everything in it. You can make this method to accept Supplier as a parameter:

```
public Account createNewAccount(Supplier<Account> accountConstructor) {
    var account = accountConstructor.get();
    account.fillEverything();
    return account;
}
```

And after that pass constructor to this method either using lambda:

```
createNewAccount(() -> new UserAccount());
```

Or using method reference:

```
createNewAccount(UserAccount::new);
```

Both variants are working.

Comment: This is not the "*what*", but the "*how*". If you link to websites, you should give a short description in case the website goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors can be passed as arugments to methods using a method reference, somewhat like a function pointer in C++.

See: http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-double-colon-operator

This can be a Function type with one argument or a BiFunction type with two arguments, either way its a lambda returning a class of the type it constructs.

Like Turing85 said though I don't think this is what you want. Passing constructors as parameters is a pretty niche use case. If you just want information on constructors,

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: "*Like Turing85 said though I don't think this is what you want.*" - And why do you then post a speculative answer? =)

Comment: Note that there is also the [Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) class from **Reflection**. It can be used too to dynamically create instances, using `constr.newInstance(...)` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...))).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example class that holds two constructors as instance variables and invokes one of them when the `constructItem` method is called. The first constructor is stored as a `Supplier` that returns an object of type `S` and the second takes a `Function` that takes type `T` and returns type `S`.

```java
public class ConstructorWrapper<T, S> {

    private final Supplier<S> construct;
    private final Function<T, S> constructFromObject;

    public ConstructorWrapper(Supplier<S> constructWithNothing, Function<T, S> constructWithObject) {
        this.construct = constructWithNothing;
        this.constructFromObject = constructWithObject;
    }

    public S constructItem(T k) {
        if (k != null) return this.construct.get();
        else return constructFromObject.apply(k);
    }
}
```

We can use the class like this to wrap creation of ArrayLists from Sets. `x` is created by invoking the constructor with no parameters and `y` is created by invoking the constructor with one parameter.

```java
ConstructorWrapper<Set, ArrayList> setToArrayList = new ConstructorWrapper<>(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::new);
ArrayList x = setToArrayList.constructItem(null);
ArrayList y = setToArrayList.constructItem(new HashSet<>());
```

Or like this to wrap creation of Sets from ArrayLists:

```java
ConstructorWrapper<ArrayList, HashSet> arrayListsToSets = new ConstructorWrapper<>(HashSet::new, HashSet::new);
HashSet x = arrayListsToSets.constructItem(null);
HashSet y = arrayListsToSets.constructItem(new ArrayList<>());
```

I used raw ArrayLists and Sets because I didn't want to clutter the code with more generics