# What is the right way to assign a data member to another data member of generic type

Tags: java, generics

```
interface IBase {
    void doJob();
}

public class MyCache<T extends IBase> {
    private T t1;
    private T t2;
    public MyCache(T t1, T t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        t1.update();
        t2 = t1.clone(); // ERROR!
    }
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to develop a generic class. In the function `init()`, I assign the copy of `t1` to `t2`. But it can't be compiled.

I'm not very good at Java. Can someone help me on this issue?

Comment: You can't clone random objects. They'd need to implement Cloneable and expose the `clone()` method. But it's [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597965/why-people-are-so-afraid-of-using-clone-on-collection-and-jdk-classes) to add a copy constructor.

Comment: "copy [constructor" is not applicable for an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2804041/592355)...but you can just call it (& implement `default`) "method": `interface IBase {
    void doJob(); [default] IBase copyMe(IBase src)[;|{...}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the contract `public Object clone()`, so to use this method in your class you shouild declare it and case `Object` to the `T`.

```java
interface IBase extends Cloneable {

    void doJob();

    void update();
    
    Object clone();

}

public class MyCache<T extends IBase> {

    private T t1;
    private T t2;

    public MyCache(T t1, T t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    private void init() {
        t1.update();
        t2 = (T)t1.clone();
    }
}
```

***P.S.** This is working solution, but at this time an outdated. It's better to use a copy constructor instead.*

Comment: `Object.clone()` is protected. It needs to be exposed in addition to implementing Cloneable.

Comment: It still needs to be implemented (by calling `super.clone()`)

Comment: Could you show me the copy-constructor solution?