# How do I change the code that is compatible with the principle of inversion of control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inversion-of-control

I use [AuthorzieAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for authentication and authorization in my web application.
How do I change HandleUnauthorizedRequest method that is compatible with the principle of inversion of control ([IOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control))?

```
public class AuthorizeUser : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return SessionContext.GetCurrentUser() != null ? true : false;
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url,
                            Area = "",
                            controller = "Account",
                            action = "Login"
                        })
                    );
    }
}
```

Comment: To start, relying on abstractions instead of implementation is a big part of IoC.  You can then use configuration to determine which concrete classes implement your abstractions.  Take a look here for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770039/examples-of-ioc-containers

Comment: [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98) may help

Comment: You can only use ***Property Injection*** in filter. Where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: I've created a new object in the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method(RedirectToRouteResult , RouteValueDictionary).I instead I use dependency injection.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url });
}
```