# Interface Type Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, clr

In chapter eight (p189) of "CLR Via C#", Jeffrey Richter states that:

"A Type constructor can be applied to interfaces (although C# doesn't allow this)"

I've done a little bit of research and I can't seem to find why an interface would ever need a type constructor, in any language. This seems like something that you would explicitly disallow in the CLR.

When would this ever be needed, and why is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is but I found another article that along the same lines that may be of interest:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619856/interface-defining-a-constructor-signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in [reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-compiler-detect-com-types) and some of its answers on SO.

It basically covers how the C# compiler instantiates COM objects based on interfaces. It's not necessarily the same situation that Richter discusses, but its an interesting case of instantiating interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in situations where you want to treat the interface as an abstract class.
Although C# doesn't support that.