# Force implementation of default constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, constraints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface defining a constructor signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619856/interface-defining-a-constructor-signature)

I have a mixed hierarchy of classes and interfaces.

For using serialisation I need a default constructor present in 
each class. I would really aprreciate if the compiler could tell
me that a default constructor is missing somewhere in the hierarchy. 
(seeing the problem at compile time, not in the later tests)

What I would like to have could be some markup or attribute,
but I could not find anything.

Something like:

```
[ForceDefaultConstructor]
interface IVeryQuickSerializable
{   
    Serialize();
    Deserialize();
}
```

would be great!

But anything like that is very appreciated.

There is a limitation: I cannot change the Serialisation.
Making it generic would solve the problem, but I do not have
the source. Writing a wrapper might do the job, but it will
have a loophole for objects deriving from the toplevel Serialisation
interface (which may not be altered).

Comment: Assuming that everything descends from `Object`, it already has a default constructor. Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: @DavidLively constructors aren't inherited; `class Foo { public Foo(int i) {...}` does **not** have a parameterless constructor

Comment: I'd like to suggest reading this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/f6364918-fc7f-4153-b020-6ce14b34820c

Although they provide something like a solution, that uses generics.

Comment: already saw that one, but there he wants some parameters, i especially want >no< parameters.

Comment: @MarcGravell constructors for base classes *are* called (inherited) when you instantiate a child class. You only need to declare a constructor `Foo() {}' when you've added a constructor that requires parameters.

Comment: The problem is, that i cannot construct a Foo if it doesn't have a default constructor in serialisation. the base default constructor will not help me out.

Comment: @MareInfinitus - ah - I didn't get that from your question. "Default constructor" is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that in an interface or attribute.

Two thoughts:

- integration test: use reflection to find all relevant classes, and check them in a test
- expose your serialization code in a generic API that uses the `T : new()` clause, i.e.

  ```
  void Serialize<T>(T obj, ...) where T : IVeryQuickSerializable, new()
  ```

Comment: Writing a wrapper is a partial solution, but maybe the fastest. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for integration tests, I made a similar use of them at several times. Last time was a few days ago, to ensure that a given set of classes was decorated with a consistent combination of custom attributes.

Comment: Yes, the more I read on those tests, the more I like the idea. We already have a somewhat big set of tests, but this one is missing.

Comment: The constraints will get me out of this i believe. Should be only minor changes to existing code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There most probably are better solutions, but you could write an application that uses reflection to inspect the assembly during the post-build event.