# Class with parametrized constructor always

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface defining a constructor signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619856/interface-defining-a-constructor-signature)

I can declare methods and properties in an Interface and impose the class that implements it to implement these methods and properties.
Similarly is it possible to impose a rule such that all my classes which implement a certain interface should always have a parametrized constructor?

Am not sure if this is possible. Just a thought.

Thanks

Comment: Nope, can't be done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619856/interface-defining-a-constructor-signature

Answer (score 4):

> Similarly is it possible to impose a rule such that all my classes which implement a certain interface should always have a parametrized constructor?

No, not through interface declarations.

You can create an abstract class instead and *it* can have a parametrized constructor - all implementing types will inherit the constructor and will be able to chain to it using the `base` keyword. Note that this will not stop you inheriting types from implementing parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 1):

No, but if your goal is to normalize how instances of an interface are constructed, define another interface that is a factory for instances of the first. In the factory interface you can impose the required construction parameters.

```
interface IFoo
{
    ...
}

interface IFooFactory
{
    IFoo CreateFoo(string param1, string param2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks..this looks like what I want. Can you please elaborate a bit more on this? How would class Foo look like?

Answer (score 0):

A class have contructor and interface cannot. So you cannot in force classes that implement certain interface to have a parameterised contructor

But you can have a class with a multiple constructors and its children can have a choice which constructor they want to use