# WCF cannot add service due - cannot obtain meta data

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have the following,

(In VS2012)

`PostCodes` is my solution it is an ASP.NET Web forms application I have two services,

`Service1` and `Service2`

Everything was working fine until I started to add some real stuff  to `IService2`. This meaning started to make constructors and I now receieve and error from the WCF test client that states (When i hit run inside my Service2.svc.cs tab)

"Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata."

here is my Web.Config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Now I have tried time and time again to allow my WCF test client to obtain the meta data by adding endpoints to the web.config file as follows

```
<services>   
  <service name="Service2" // 
           behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
    <endpoint address=http://localhost/Service2
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="IService2" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/Service2/mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

To clairfy My solution is called PostCodes, I have two services, Service1 and Service2

The above did not work, and I still get the error when running the WCF Test Client...

I am not running this online or anything this is purely to run through the Test Client and on my local machine.

So my question is - What have I done wrong in adding these end points and how can I fix it.

Any advice would be great,

Post below for any clarifications if needed

Regards

Comment: When you run your WCF service from VS2010 devlopment server, are you able to see the WDSL structure if the WCF service ?

Comment: @dreamweiver Sorry i am a bit unfamilier with what you're talking about, I am running this in Visual studio 2012... How would i go about running it in VS2010 dev server?

Comment: thats quite simple, just run your WCF service in VS2010, it will run the service in the default browser, where in you can see the WCF service`s URL,just click over it, this will display the complete meta data from your WCF service.refer this link,http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-IIS-Hosting.aspx.

Comment: I don't even have 2010 installed :(

Comment: This service used to work before I started adding some constructors to my classes that's why I'm finding this a little odd

Comment: If i take out my constructors it works fine... -.- as inthe constructors in my IService.cs file

Comment: oh, you had mentioned in question about the IDE as VS2010.anyway can post those constructors in your question, let me have a look into it first

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36769/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-jim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the reason, you cant define a constructor in interface, as you cannot instantiate them. here is a relevant SO for your better understanding

[Interface defining a constructor signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619856/interface-defining-a-constructor-signature)

**Resolution:**

There is always a class implementing the interface , which you could find in the same WCF service project.you will find the code behind file name within .svc file inside your WCF project.whatever you wanted add within the interfaced constructor, add the same inside the constructor defined in the class.

Happy Coding:)