# Force Class to Have Constructor with Parameter of Type

Tags: c#, constructor

Is there a way where I can force a class to have to have a contructor that accepts an int parameter?

For example if I had a class called `ItemDetail` and inherited from a class called `ForceConstructor` I would have to have a constructor in my `ItemDetail` class that accepted an int parameter?

```
public class ItemDetail : ForceConstructor
{
    public ItemDetail(Data.Entities.Item item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }

    //MUST HAVE THIS
    public ItemDetail(int id)
    {
        this.Item = ItemService.GetItem(id);
    }
}
```

So any class that inherited from `ForceConstructor` would have to have the int id constructor.

Comment: XY perhaps. Why do you care how a derived class constructor works

Comment: Those two constructors make no sense.  If you have to have the second one, remove the first one.

Comment: Best you can do is have a constructor on `ForceConstructor` that takes an `int` and no default constructor.  Then the inheriting class has to pass an int to that, but it doesn't have to get the int from the constructor.  In short there is no way to enforce classes to have a particular signature for their constructors.

Comment: when you ForceConstructor has a constructor of ''public ForceConstructor(int id)'' that's mean all his derived class have that constructor too. You don't need explicit to force, it implicit forced.

Comment: Maybe the Factory pattern is the droid you are looking for? But I have to agree that does sound like a XY problem first and foremost.

Comment: @LarsTech This is a Xamarin app and one is used to pass the item from a list when selected. The int one is for Deeplinking. I need to use the Id in the constructor so I dont have to have a switch statement for each deeplinking page.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. It has to be checked at runtime, either directly by parsing the reflection data, or indirectly by just trying to bind to it (`dynamic`).

Unlike C++, C# has no meta-programming duck typing, and you can't declare constructors in interfaces or base classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this with `abstract`

the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41685659/2343826) should give you a better idea.  HTH